# Draw 32-bits with alpha channel from resources using Direct2D

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, alphablending, direct2d, wic

I have a legacy MCF application that displays some images (bmp 32-bits with alpha channel information) by pre-multiplying the images and using `CDC::AlphaBlend` method.

I would like to introduce some new graphics using Direct2D but I don't want to migrate all the images to png or other formats.

I managed to draw a bmp image from a file but I'm facing problems to get the image from resources and also the displayed image does not use the alpha channel information.

So could anybody help me out with this?

This is my code to create the bitmap:

```
hr = pIWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(   L"D:\\image.bmp", 
                                                NULL, 
                                                GENERIC_READ, 
                                                WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand, 
                                                &pDecoder);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Create the initial frame.
    hr = pDecoder->GetFrame(0, &pSource);
}

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    //create a Direct2D bitmap from the WIC bitmap.
    hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
        pSource,
        NULL,
        ppBitmap
        );

}
```

This is the code to draw the bitmap:

```
m_pRenderTarget->DrawBitmap(
    m_pBitmap,
    D2D1::RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make an IStream from the resource to pass to IWICImagingFactory::CreateDecoderFromStream.

Since resources are available in memory (assuming the module that contains them is loaded), the easiest way to do that is to create an IWICStream object using IWICImagingFactory::CreateStream and initialize it using IWICStream::InitializeFromMemory.

To get the size of the resource and a pointer to the first byte, use the FindResource, LoadResource, LockResource, and SizeofResource functions.

If your bitmap's header uses BI_BITFIELDS to specify a format with alpha data, I believe WIC will respect that. I don't have any experience with Direct2D, so I can't say if you need to do anything further to make it use alpha data.

If you can't use BI_BITFIELDS (or if that doesn't work), you can write your own IWICBitmapSource implementation that wraps the frame's IWICBitmapSource. You should be able to pass most calls directly to the frame source, and supply your own GetPixelFormat method that returns the real format of your image data. Alternatively, you can create an IWICBitmap with the format you want, lock the bitmap, and copy in the pixel data from the frame source.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I will give it a try as soon as possible (more priority things than investigation now). Anyway the problem with alpha channel is not being "respected" now when I open the bitmap from a file...so I doubt it will be when opening using a stream.